# ASP.NET Email Form Return message after form is submitted

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

Sorry if this has been addressed. I just can't get it to work. I have a email contact form. I have the form working ok. It is sending an email. However, after the form is submitted I was either a message to pop up or be redirected to a different page saying that their email was sent successfully and we'll respond as we can. I've tried RedirectActionTo and some other things, but I cannot get it to work. Here is my code.

```
       public ActionResult ContactForm(ContactModel emailModel)
    {            
            MailMessage oMail = new MailMessage();

            oMail.From = new MailAddress("no-reply@domain.com", "Web Contact Form");
            oMail.To.Add("email@domain.com");
            oMail.Subject = emailModel.Subject;
            string body = "Name: " + emailModel.Name + "\n"
                        + "Email: " + emailModel.Email + "\n"
                        + "Website: " + emailModel.Website + "\n"
                        + "Phone: " + emailModel.Phone + "\n\n"
                        + emailModel.Message;

            oMail.Body = body;

            if (SendMessage(oMail))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Message");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Error");
            }
            return View();
    }
    private bool SendMessage(MailMessage oMail)
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("relay-hosting.secureserver.net");
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email@domain.com", "********", "domaion.com");
        try
             {
                 client.Send(oMail);
                 return true;
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 this.exception = ex;
                 return false;
             } }

}
```

Thank for your help.

Comment: @Bill Martin. Well the good news is that return RedirectToAction worked, kind of. It redirected me to the confirmation page. However, it did it right away with out giving me a chance to enter information into the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because the action is completed without waiting for result.

here is simplified version of my implementation

after in your controller you can set up your response such as:

```
public class ContactModel
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public string Website { get; set; }
            public string Phone { get; set; }
            public string Message { get; set; }
            public string Subject { get; set; }
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

            ContactModel model = new ContactModel();
            model.Email = "test@email.com";
            model.Message = "message";
            model.Name = "name";
            model.Subject = "subject";
            model.Website = "http://test.com";
            ContactForm(model);

            return View();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Contacts the form.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Returns view to display the form and fill</returns>
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public ActionResult ContactForm()
        {
            return View(new ContactModel());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Contacts the form.
        /// If model is valid we will go ahead and process emailing 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="emailModel">The email model.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult ContactForm(ContactModel emailModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                MailMessage oMail = new MailMessage();

                oMail.From = new MailAddress("no-reply@domain.com", "Web Contact Form");
                oMail.To.Add("email@domain.com");
                oMail.Subject = emailModel.Subject;
                string body = "Name: " + emailModel.Name + "\n"
                              + "Email: " + emailModel.Email + "\n"
                              + "Website: " + emailModel.Website + "\n"
                              + "Phone: " + emailModel.Phone + "\n\n"
                              + emailModel.Message;

                oMail.Body = body;

                if (SendMessage(oMail))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Message");
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Error");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return View(emailModel);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sends the message.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="oMail">The o mail.</param>
        /// <returns>Boolean success.</returns>
        private bool SendMessage(MailMessage oMail)
        {
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("relay-hosting.secureserver.net");
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email@domain.com", "********", "domaion.com");
            try
            {
                client.Send(oMail);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.exception = ex;
                return false;
            }
        }
```

The view is redirecting because i guess you have not split Type of the request over the method. and therefore its going straight to redirect.

this is done by

> [AcceptVerbs(Http.Get)] or  [AcceptVerbs(Http.Post)]

hope this helps

> To pass message:
>
> ```
> TemData["message"] = "pass message between controllers like this"
> ```
>
> public AcionResult Message(string message){ //here choose
>   ViewData["message"] = TempData["message];
>
> return View(); }
>
> or
>
> ```
>     return RedirectToAction("Message", new{message = "pass message between controllers"});
>  `enter code here`    where 
> public AcionResult Message(string message){
> //or if you are using parameter
> ViewData["message"] = message;
>
>
> return View();
> }
> ```

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of new with form code on mvc. I understand your code. Although I have a couple of questions. After "//create client" do I need anything? And after "//set all stuff you need" that's where I put the oMail stuff, but do I need "MailMessage oMail = new System.Web.Mail.MailMessage();"

Comment: Sorry for the late response, just got back from the weekend. Quick question. I have an error, "this.exception = ex;" exception does not contain a definition. How do I correct that?

Comment: With the code I have up above, it is still redirecting to the message page with out letting me enter in info

Comment: @LarsHovden: the exception does not need to be there its more precaution

Comment: ok is there a better way that to redirect? the info you manually put in the ActionResult Index() came through, but no message. And when I took out that it contact form didn't come up. Sorry for this. It's driving me nuts

Comment: I now have two ActionResults for ContactForm which is giving me an error

Comment: i did not add that in message pass the message along

Answer (score 0):

your IIS isn't set up right, this is also obsolete, you should be using the System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient instead, see [SocttGu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432854.aspx) post on it